# Merge multiple jsons with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I need to merge two or more JSON objects. The JSON are structured in this way:

```
var data1 = {
    "key": "Data 1",
    "values": [
        {
            "period": 1380585600000,
            "value": 8.1
        },
        {
            "period": 1380672000000,
            "value": 8.15
        }
     ]}

var data2 = {
    "key": "Data 2",
    "values": [
        {
            "period": 1372183600000,
            "value": 5.0
        },
        {
            "period": 1380663000000,
            "value": 4.35
        }
     ]}
```

I want to have a new object structured like this:

```
var dataMerged =[
{
    "key": "Data 1",
    "values": [
        {
            "period": 1380585600000,
            "value": 8.1
        },
        {
            "period": 1380672000000,
            "value": 8.15
        }
    ]
},
{
    "key": "Data 2",
    "values": [
        {
            "period": 1372183600000,
            "value": 5
        },
        {
            "period": 1380663000000,
            "value": 4.35
        }
    ]
}
]
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compose them together into an array:

```
var dataMerged=[data1,data2];
```

If you want to use jQuery, use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

```
var dataMerged=$.extend({},data1,data2);
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use $.merge

```
  var newobject=$.merge(object1, object2);
```